# Is it possible to get the reference of other activities view?

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-service

I have a floating widget that is running on a background service and I have inflated a view with it

```
mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget, null);
```

but now I have a need to callOnClick() on one of its sub-views from main-activity.

Can I do that, I mean can I get the reference for it, if yes how.

If it were a class I could have used interface but it's a service.

Comment: Bind the `Service` with activity . and then call its methods .

Comment: @ADM thank you, i implemented it and it worked fine